# I/O warning : failed to load external entity XML file

Tags: c, xml, xcode

I have a basic XML file that want to read try.xml; it is placed in the same directory of the project.
[image: the project tree is showed here]

I used this simple code to read an XML file, but somehow fail to read the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

int main(){   xmlDoc *doc = NULL;   xmlNode *root_element = NULL;

  doc = xmlReadFile("dummy.xml", NULL, 0);

  if (doc == NULL) {
    printf("Could not parse the XML file");   }

  root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

  print_xml(root_element, 1);

  xmlFreeDoc(doc);

  xmlCleanupParser(); }
```

The error is

```
  I/O warning : failed to load external entity "dummy.xml"
```

If condition is run. Output is: Could not parse the XML file

I also tried various paths as parameters for xmlReadFile such as:

```
  doc = xmlReadFile("../helloWorld/dummy.xml", NULL, 0);
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE to compile? If so which one? Check where the binary is actually built as that is likely the current directory and the place where the file needs to be stored. Not necessarily in the source directory.

Comment: You seem to be using an IDE of some kind for development. When running a program from an IDE, the programs *working directory* might not be what you expect. In this case it's probably not the `helloWorld` directory. You need to check your project and run settings.

Comment: As said by previous remarks very probably your current directory is Products, in that case `doc = xmlReadFile("../helloWorld/dummy.xml", NULL, 0);` will work. Out of that problem when `if (doc == NULL)` is true after the `printf` you need to stop program execution, or put the rest of code in an `else` branch

Comment: I use xcode, with built in C, and use brew to install libxml. I created a command line project.

Comment: @MinhPham if you start you program by hand in a terminal being in *helloWorld/helloWorld* that works isn't it ? Do `xmlReadFile("../helloWorld/dummy.xml", NULL, 0);` it will probably work using your IDE and even being already in the right directory doing by hand. Else print the current directory at the beginning of *main* to know it

Comment: I tried to run the program from the terminal and discovered that the program execution file was placed entirely somewhere else, thus cannot file the dummy.xml. After putting the xml on the same folder with the execution file, it does work. Thanks you all for the help.